# Understanding recordreader in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, reduce

I am new to hadoop and while trying to learn Custom Recordreader i have a doubt , in link here : [here](http://analyticspro.org/2012/08/01/wordcount-with-custom-record-reader-of-textinputformat/), author used start -1 character i understands that it might be possible that if the last line in earlier split  has few character in next block

my question is if we have block size of 128 Mb and lines are split across the block then we have to take care of not rereading or skip the file content but how we can implement this by just reducing one character from start.

Please confirm during the initialize function  does the value of start variable is always zero (for every split) if we have files ending with boundaries. 
what will be the value of start -1 in case of line across blocks

Thanks

Comment: Where Does Start -1 points in the file offset , does start -1 means offset of last line from block 1 (with line across the blocks). I belive start is only initilized to zero only for first block and then the next value of start will be 128*1024Mb

Comment: why are you not asking the author himself why he choses to start at -1?